# Old transactions remain unconfirmed after redownloading the blockchain

Tags: bitcoin-core

I received a runaway exception error then deleted everything but wallet.dat from the data directory and opened bitcoin-qt to redownload the blockchain.  Transactions larger than 0.00016 btc remain unconfirmed on my overview page even as they show as confirmed on the transactions page.  These larger transactions are also missing when I go to the send coins page, click inputs, then click the drop down icon next to my address.  I have tried downloading the blockchain twice and the same thing happened both times.  I did not allow the blockchain to fully download because of the error and because I have a new large transaction that is not yet part of my wallet.dat file.  I am running version 0.8.1.  I imported my private keys from blockchain.info in May.  Any suggestions?